# Posting score to Facebook app

Tags: c#, facebook, post, facebook-c#-sdk

I've been trawling the answers in SO concerning posting a score to a Facebook app, and I still can't get it to work. The code I'm using is here -

```
private const string FACEBOOK_POST_SCORE_URL = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/scores?access_token={0}";

public void PostScoreAsync(Action<FacebookResponse> response, FacebookScore score)
    {

        try
        {
            // Append the user's access token to the URL
            Uri fullUri = new Uri(string.Format(FACEBOOK_POST_SCORE_URL, AccessToken));

            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(score);

            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(fullUri);
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";

            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                writer.Write(json);
            }

            request.BeginGetResponse(WebRequestCallback, new FacebookResult
            {
                Request = request,
                Response = response
            });

        }
        catch (ThreadAbortException)
        {
            throw;
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            if (response != null)
                response(FacebookResponse.NetworkError);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { 
            if (response != null)
                response(FacebookResponse.OtherError);
        }

    }
```

We're using webViews rather than iOS / Android Facebook SDKs, as we're building a cross-platform app in Mono.

Obviously I have the access token & the app appears to have full permissions to do what I want to do, which I allowed after login. Any thoughts appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure that `access_token` you have is the one for Application and not for User?

Comment: Definitely correct access token, but thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found out (from a colleague) that the Facebook graph api won't take json encoded parameters, so we sorted it like so -

```
string parameters = "score=" + score.Score;

var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(fullUri);
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
{
    writer.Write(parameters);
}
```

Now it works fine - hopefully this'll help someone else not have the same problem.